# Odoo 16. Mostrar datos de un array construido en una vista

Tags: odoo

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Odoo 16 y necesito mostrar una información que construyo en un array en un método en una vista personalizada.
Este es el botón que me ejecuta el método

```
<button id="btn_get_commision_report" name="get_data_for_tree_view" string="Get Commision Report" type="object" class="btn-primary" icon="fa-check"/>
```

que ejecuta este método

```
    def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
        data = [{'company': 'Company 1', 'month': 'january', 'total': '100'}, 
                {'company': 'Company 2', 'month': 'january', 'total': '200'}, 
                {'company': 'Company 3', 'month': 'january', 'total': '130'},]

        action = {
            'name': 'Data from Method',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_type': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'commission.report.month',
            'target': 'current',
            'data': data,
        }
        return action
```

y esta es a vista

```
        <record id="commission_report_month_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">commission.report.month.view.tree</field>
            <field name="model">commission.report.month</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="" create="false" edit="false">
                    <field name="company"/>
                    <field name="month"/>
                    <field name="total"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

de este modelo

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
class CommissionReportMonth(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'commission.report.month'
    _description = 'Commission Report Month TransientModel'

    company = fields.Char(string='Company')
    month = fields.Char(string='Month')
    total = fields.Char(string='Total')
```

el problema es que la vista me la visualiza sin los datos de 'data', así en blanco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede ayudar a entender qué estoy haciendo mal ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te falta en si es guardar en la base de datos esos datos que estas intentando mostrar.
Por ejemplo modificando tu codigo para que funcione una primera version de lo que te digo seria asi:

```py
    def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
        self.env['commission.report.month'].create([
            {'company': 'Company 1', 'month': 'january', 'total': '100'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 2', 'month': 'january', 'total': '200'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 3', 'month': 'january', 'total': '130'}
        ])
        return {
            'name': 'Data from Method',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_type': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'commission.report.month',
            'target': 'current',
        }
```

Pero esto aun tiene el problema de que cada vez que hagas click en el boton se te va a guardar en la base de datos esos 3 registros adicionales a los que ya estarian de clicks anteriores.

Para resolver esto podrias ponerle un dominio en el action que incluya solamente los records que creaste como parte del click del boton:

```py
    def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
        records = self.env['commission.report.month'].create([
            {'company': 'Company 1', 'month': 'january', 'total': '100'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 2', 'month': 'january', 'total': '200'}, 
            {'company': 'Company 3', 'month': 'january', 'total': '130'}
        ])
        return {
            'name': 'Data from Method',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_type': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'commission.report.month',
            'target': 'current',
            'domain': [('id', 'in', records.ids)]
        }
```

o podrias tener un modelo intermedio que tenga una relacion con one2many o many2many con `commission.report.month` para entonces asociar los nuevos records con tu modelo y retornar en el action el res_id de ese record que enlaza a los demas, pero entonces no mostrarias un listado sino un form con un listado dentro.

Comment: Gracias por responder, podrías decirme cómo hacerlo una opción del menú, tengo esto:
```
<record id="report_function" model="ir.actions.server">
 <field name="name">commission_report_month</field>
 <field name="model_id" ref="model_commission_report_month"/>
 <field name="state">code</field>
 <field name="code">model.get_data_for_tree_view()</field>
 </record>
<menuitem id="_menu_root" name="My App">
<menuitem name="Reports by Month" id="report_month_menu" action="report_function" />
</menuitem>
```
Pero no se muestra la vista, ejecuta el método pero se queda allí

Comment: En una accion de servidor no tienes que retornar el action dict, solo tienes que asignarle el valor a una variable 'action' y listo.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/actions.html Mira la nota que ponen en el campo codigo

Comment: Mil gracias por tu ayuda, ya me funcionó, al fin un respiro

Comment: puedes votar la respuesta aca tambien porfa?

Comment: Supongo que ahora es cuando empezara a desarrollarse el tema que estaba trabado. Si necesitan resolver o desarrollar algo complicado me pueden escribir y les cotizo el desarrollo a la medida o la consultoria